# Magento 2 massaction delete not working

Tags: grid, magento-2.0, massaction

My custom module massaction action code as below:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Modulename\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;

/**
 * Class MassDelete
 */
class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
     protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

     protected $moduleFactory;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        Filter $filter,
         CollectionFactory $module
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->moduleFactory = $module;
         $this->filter = $filter;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    /**
     * Execute action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException|\Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $deleteIds = $this->getRequest()->getParams('selected');

        $collection = $this->moduleFactory->create();

        $collection->addFieldToFilter('id', array('in' => $deleteIds));

        $count = 0;
        foreach ($collection as $child) {
            $child->delete();
            $count++;
        }

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $count));

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Using above code if I select some record it is working fine.But if I select all it is not working (no one record deleted).Also I have tried using below code.

```
<?php    
    namespace Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

    use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
    use Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Modulename\CollectionFactory;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;

    /**
     * Class MassDelete
     */
    class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
    {
         protected $_coreRegistry = null;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
         */
        protected $resultPageFactory;

         protected $moduleFactory;

        /**
         * @param Action\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
         */
        public function __construct(
            Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            Filter $filter,
             CollectionFactory $module
        ) {
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
            $this->moduleFactory = $module;
             $this->filter = $filter;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }


        /**
         * Execute action
         *
         * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException|\Exception
         */
        public function execute()
        {
            $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->moduleFactory->create());

            $count = 0;
            foreach ($collection as $child) {
                $child->delete();
                $count++;
            }

            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $count));

            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        }
    }
```

Above code gives error as below:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ '' inconnu dans where
>   clause, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `mytable` AS
>   `main_table` WHERE (`` IN('', '', '', '', '', ''))

ui_component code:

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">module_index_grid.module_index_grid.module_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">module_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="module/index/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>            
        </massaction>
```

Model code `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Model/ResourceModel/Module.php`

```
 <?php
    namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel;

    class Module extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
    {
        /**
         * Initialize resource model
         *
         * @return void
         */
        protected function _construct()
        {       
            $this->_init('mytable', 'module_id');
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Module;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Module\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, Filter $filter, CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Dispatch request
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
        $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $item->delete();
        }

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 element(s) have been deleted.', $collectionSize));

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Works perfectly for me.

Good luck! :)

Edit: if it won't work, it can be also something wrong with your grid definition, so please post it here too

Do you have following code in 'columns' node of your ui_component?

```
<selectionsColumn name="ids">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">module_id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</selectionsColumn>
```

Check if you have following line in your Model\ResourceModel\Module\Collection.php file:

```
protected $_idFieldName = 'module_id';
```

Comment: It is not working i have tried with same code in my second try

Comment: Then add here also code of your massactions definition from ui_component

Comment: Thanks.Updated question with ui_component code can you please check it

Comment: Check my edit, do you have exact same code?

Comment: Yes it is in ui_component.

Comment: Can you post here also content of your Model/ResourceModel/Module.php file?

Comment: Everything right here, now Model/ResourceModel/Module/Collection.php :)

Comment: Or simply check last edit of my answer :)

Comment: It is not working.There is issue in di.xml i have resolved it.But you have defined some step of debug is good it is useful for others as well.Thank you so much.

Comment: @BartłomiejSzubert from where we need to include as i did not found any CollectionFactory

Comment: `CollectionFactory` is automatically generated if you already have `Collection` class in same namespace.

Comment: The last piece `$_idFieldName` solved it for me!

Comment: Yes correct @quickshiftin . Same works for me too :)

Comment: @Ideo : The last piece of code is not mentioned everywhere, and yes that is what makes it work. Good answer and research too.

Comment: How to use walk method on collection instead of looping collection?

Comment: working perfect :)

Comment: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document::delete
I got this error still please help me

Answer (score 7):

Follow this process to implement Massaction delete

> Namespace: Prince
>
> Modulename: PincodeChecker

**1) Use this code in UI Grid file(prince_pincodechecker_index.xml) before**

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">prince_pincodechecker_index.prince_pincodechecker_index.prince_pincodechecker_columns.ids</item>
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">pincode_id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <action name="delete">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="prince_pincodechecker/pincodechecker/massDelete"/>
                <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete staffs</item>
                    <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected staffs?</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </action>
</massaction>
```

**You must have define indexField**

```
<selectionsColumn name="ids">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">pincode_id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</selectionsColumn>
```

**2) Create MassDelete.php controller**

> app/code/Prince/PincodeChecker/Controller/Adminhtml/Pincodechecker/MassDelete.php

```
<?php
namespace Prince\PincodeChecker\Controller\Adminhtml\Pincodechecker;

class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {

    protected $_filter;

    protected $_collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter $filter,
        \Prince\PincodeChecker\Model\ResourceModel\Pincodechecker\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
        ) {
        $this->_filter            = $filter;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        try{ 

            $logCollection = $this->_filter->getCollection($this->_collectionFactory->create());
            //echo "<pre>";
            //print_r($logCollection->getData());
            //exit;
            foreach ($logCollection as $item) {
                $item->delete();
            }
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Log Deleted Successfully.'));
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('Prince_Pincodechecker/pincodechecker/index'); //Redirect Path
    }

     /**
     * is action allowed
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed() {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Prince_PincodeChecker::view');
    }
}
```

**3) Define protected $_idFieldName in collection.php**

> app/code/Prince/PincodeChecker/Model/ResourceModel/Pincodechecker/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Prince\PincodeChecker\Model\ResourceModel\Pincodechecker;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'pincode_id';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'Prince\PincodeChecker\Model\Pincodechecker',
            'Prince\PincodeChecker\Model\ResourceModel\Pincodechecker'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Prince your code working for me

Comment: hi @Prince, how can we add Massaction tree drop down here, Assign as first option, then once that is clicked, All other users in the drop down.

Answer (score 3):

> You can try this code :-

```
public function execute()

{ 
    $collection = $this->_filter->getCollection($this->_collectionFactory->create());
    $recordDeleted = 0;

    foreach ($collection as $record) {

        $deleteItem = $this->_objectManager->get('Vendor\Modulename\Model\modelname')->load($record->getId());
        $deleteItem->delete();
        $recordDeleted++;
    }

    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $recordDeleted));
    return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT)->setPath('*/*/index');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just try inside your controller file,

```
 public function execute()
    {
        $deleteIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('teams');
        if (!is_array($deleteIds) || empty($deleteIds)) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Please select item(s).'));
        } else {
            try {
                foreach ($deleteIds as $itemId) {
                    $post = $this->_objectManager->get('Package\Module\Model\Module')->load($itemId);
                    $post->delete();
                }
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                    __('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', count($itemIds))
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');       
    }
```

In above method you have to just pass your model file instead of `Package\Module\Model\Module`.
This is working code.

Comment: Yes it is working but it is only delete some records, It will not delete if I select all. I have tried same also posted in question in first section.

Comment: have you checked above method or not, i have call object inside foreach so plz check using above method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
            <massaction name="listing_massaction">
                <action name="order_delete">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">order_delete</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Order</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="sales/order/massdelete"/>
                            <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Order(s)</item>
                                <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan\'t to delete selected items?</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </action>
            </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```