# Is it Necessary to create layout.xml for massDelete file?

Tags: massaction

**here my delete action**

```
<action name="delete">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="faq/cat/massDelete"/>
                <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete FAQs</item>
                    <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected FAQs?</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </action>
```

when I clicked on delete not working

Answer (score 1):

no need to create XML file for that.

you just need to controller file for that.

> **ComnayName\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\massDelete.php**

Make sure name of file is massDelete not massdelete.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**yes It is Necessary, You can this code in your Layout.xml files:-**

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">module_index_grid.module_index_grid.module_columns.ids</item>
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">module_id</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <action name="delete">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="module/index/massDelete"/>
                            <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                                <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </action>            
 </massaction>
```

Comment: ok fine but when i clicked on delete it take me on http://localhost/magento_2_2_4/index.php/admin/faq/cat/massDelete/key/18027d38700b079273354edd2ace2656ac00fbdd4865a9b60af07b75b6c7afe2/

Comment: when you click on it you will be redirected  {module/index/massDelete}

Comment: so i have to create module_index_massdelete.xml or not

Comment: you can follow this acceptable answer:- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112072/magento-2-massaction-delete-not-working